# Nginx Proxy uploading to s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using nginx proxy to force all traffic through HTTPS. However, I have a page (/upload) which posts to /upload-downloadable which then uploads the users files using a stream to aws (bucketname.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com)

It uploads as I can see it on AWS s3 bucket, but doesn't respond back to the server to tell the user? Works without the proxy perfectly, but not with my current config.

So it does Client -> AWS, but AWS->Server/Client doesn't work.

Any ideas?

```
upstream site {
    server 127.0.0.1:1337;
}

upstream project {
     server localhost:27017;
}

# HTTP — redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS — proxy all requests to the Node app
server {
    # Enable HTTP/2
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name tryhackme.com;

    error_page 502 /down.html;
    location /down.html {
        root /var/www/html;
    }

    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /var/www/html/down.html;

    # Use the Let’s Encrypt certificates
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    # Include the SSL configuration from cipherli.st
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:28017;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_read_timeout 3600;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:1337/;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you solved this?
What do you mean by `but doesn't respond back to the server to tell the user? `. You mean https response not coming to the browser?